# Determine the limit $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0}\varepsilon\textbf{E}(|X|^{1-\varepsilon})$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a Cauchy random variable with desnity $f(x)=\frac1\pi\frac1{1+x^2}$. We know that $\textbf{E}|X|=\infty$, but $\textbf{E}(|X|^{1-\varepsilon})<\infty$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Determine the limit $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0}\varepsilon\textbf{E}(|X|^{1-\varepsilon})$. $\textit{HINT: Split the integral at a well chosen point.}$

So far what I have is that
$$
\textbf{E}(|X|^{1-\varepsilon})=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{|x|^{1-\varepsilon}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1-\varepsilon}}{1+x^2}.
$$
But from here I don't know where to go in order to simplify this integral and then to calculate the limit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try integrating by parts maybe; the fraction $1/(1+x^2)$ can be integrated with trigonometric or hyperbolic substitutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the integral at $x=1$ and substitute $x=y^{1/\varepsilon}$ for $\int_{1}^{\infty}$. Then

$$ \varepsilon \mathbf{E}[|X|^{1-\varepsilon}]
= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\varepsilon x^{1-\varepsilon}}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{y^{-2}}{y^{-2/\varepsilon}+1} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

Both integrals are suitable for applying the dominated convergence theorem, yielding

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \varepsilon \mathbf{E}[|X|^{1-\varepsilon}]
= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} 0 \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{1}^{\infty} y^{-2} \, \mathrm{d}y
= \frac{2}{\pi} $$